# Field 'id' doesn't have a default value in grails

Tags: grails

Im creating a simple app using these technologies grails, netbeans and mysql.

And I always get this error message:

> Field 'id' doesn't have a default value

I understand a bit what that meant so I focus on the id generator key.

This is my profit.groovy

```
package samplegrailsapp

import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
class DailyProfit {
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Date date;
    double profit; 
    static constraints = {

        })
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator:'assigned', name:'date'
    }
}
```

the date variable is my primary key in the my table. SO based on what I understood, I need to specify the column name that I would be using as my primary key. The problem is I still get the same error. What else did I miss so I can make it work?

Comment: Do you have to use a Date as primary key? Can't you use a normal id and apply a unique constarint to the date?

Answer (score 1):

I follow on corky_bantam that its weird to use a date a PK.

However if thats your case, you'll need to make sure the date is set when you create the Profit object
You could try with `beforeInsert`:

package samplegrailsapp

```
import java.text.DateFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import org.grails.databinding.BindingFormat
class DailyProfit {
    @BindingFormat('yyyy-MM-dd')
    Date date = new Date();
    double profit; 
    static constraints = {

        })
    }

    static mapping = {
        version false
        id generator:'assigned', name:'date'
    }

   def beforeInsert() {
      if (date == null) {
         date = new Date()
      }
   }

}
```

Comment: Like Frederic said, since you're using an assigned generator you'll need to assign a value to your pk before you call save. For more info on generators see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id-generator